# Finding points outside two lanes

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-curves

I have two set of points. One set defines the left lane and other set the right lane. And I also have another set of points(black and purple below) and I need to find points in third set which are outside these two lanes. From the below figure I need to extract all purple points.

If they are two straight lines I can just find the points on right side of right line and on left side of left line to filter these points.  Since lanes are not straight I cannot use this approach. Is there a way I can filter the points outsides these lanes efficiently?

[image]

Comment: Do you know which set a given point is in? If you create a straight line between two points (one in each set) can you tell if it crosses either line ? If so, for each point in left set, cycle through all the points in right set to see if you cross a line. If not, you have two interior points - remove them from both sets. Loop through all points in the left set on remaining right set points. You need the region between the lines to be star shaped so that straight  lines between interior points do not cross either line. No idea how efficient that might be, especially if you have a lot of points.

Comment: @Paul Sorry I did not mention that points which needs to be segregated are present in another set. Extremely sorry for the confusion

Comment: Are your left and right boundaries polygonal?

Comment: What do you meant by polygonal?

Comment: Are the boundaries essentially broken lines formed by connecting the dots?

Comment: We only have points which represent these two lines

Comment: Well, how do you define “outside” and “inside?”

Comment: Inside is any points between these two lanes and other points are considered outside

Comment: I guess you have coordinates for the points making up the left line L, the right line R and your set of scattered points S. If your coordinates are on a grid then maybe each point in S has a vertical component which is in L and R? If so, discard that point in S if its horizontal component is left of the corresponding point in L or right of the one in R. If points in S do not have vertical components in L and R then, for L, find the two points in L with vertical components either side of the points in S. Discard the point in S if it is left of the rightmost L point.

Comment: @Paul: This works for axis parallel lanes. But in our case we have points which form left and right lanes which are not parallel to axis and are oriented with different angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a computational geometry problem.

Make a triangle with the closest points in Left set. check the points x coordinates. If they are < that given point p. then p is on the right side of "those two points", otherwise p is on the left of the left.

Do the same with Right set.

However this may "sometimes" work if $Max[L_{x}] < Min[R_{x}]$. If there is a knot then the problem has to be redefined.

Sometimes it will give wrong results if $\exists t\in L \;: q_{x}<t_{x}<p_{x} \;and\; t_{y}>p_{y} \;and\; q_{y}>r_{y} $ and q,r are the closest points to p to make a triangle